# Usage of WP plugin to access Facebook photo feed now requires review/approval to use Page Public Content Access endpoint

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am using a Wordppress plugin, [WP Embed Facebook](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-embed-facebook/), to display a "live" photo feed from an album on a Facebook page/account I have control over. It used to work fine, displaying thumbnails in one of my footer widgets that when clicked opened in a lightbox. Lately, instead of said thumbnails, the following message is disalyed:

> Error: (#10) To use ‘Page Public Content Access’, your use of this
>   endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this
>   ‘Page Public Content Access’ feature for review please read our
>   documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review. (only visible to
>   admins)

(see far right footer widget at http://www.sugaroafculinary.com)

In following the link in the error message, it would seem that my "app" (i.e. the web page using the plugin) needs to undergo a review/approval process from Facebook, which seems to me to be quite the excessive set of hoops to jump through just to access content on my own page, but I digress...

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, they require access to the "app" in test mode so that they can see it in acton. In an attempt to meet this requirement, I:

1. logged into my FB app dashboard where the plugin required me to create an app in order to get an App ID and an App Secret anyway. No big deal.
2. Created a 'test app' from that from that app and configured the plugin to use the test app's App ID and App Secret

The long and the short of my *current* issue is that, I get the same error message with the test app as with the original. I was under the impression that being a *test* app, access to the endpoint would be allowed. Not so much. I don't know how I can provide Facebook access to my working test app if it produces the same error as the production version.

I'm sure i'll run into more snags with the remaining hoops I'm jumping through, but for now if anyone had any advice for how I can get the test app access to that endpoint so it can be viewed in a working state for FB review, I'd be ecstatic.

OR there's the possibility that I've misinterpreted the requirements - if it looks like that might be the case, please do not hesitate to bring that to my attention either.

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

I found the following that sounds like it might indicate that if "the person" who is the publisher of the WP page containing the plugin is the "the person" who is an admin of the app in the FB system, the endpoint is accessible.

> "While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review,
>   your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is
>   true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an
>   admin, developer, or tester role on the app. If you want the app to be
>   able to access public content on other Pages, you must submit this
>   feature for review. Once you set your app to live mode, it will not be
>   able to see any Page public content without this feature."

Now what exactly does "the person" mean? I added the FB account that has the same email address as the publisher of the WP page as an admin of the app in the App Dashboard, but the results are the same. I can't think of any way (other than by email address) that Facebook would be able to figure out that a WP user is the "same person". Am I missing something here?

Comment: You Can try with other plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting for Page Public Content Access would be the wrong thing to do here to begin with.

> to display a "live" photo feed from an album on a Facebook page/account I have control over.

So that makes it *not* public access to begin with - that feature is for accessing public content of pages you *don’t* have admin access to.

Accessing the photos of your own page requires a page access token - and getting that in return requires the page admin to grant `manage_pages` permission to the app.
If the plugin is showing you an API response talking about Page Public Content Access, then it means it did not use a proper page token for the request to begin with.

Now I don’t know this plugin, and whether it is prepared to ask for that when retrieving an access token, and if so whether something else goes wrong. I would suggest you contact the plugin author for support.

But again, Page Public Content Access is *not* what you need here.

Comment: Phheeeeeew thank you! I thought  was going crazy. I am familiar with page access tokens. The plugin dose not provide anywhere to add anything other than the APP ID and the App Secret. And unfortunately, being a free plugin, the author does not does not respond to to **any** of the numerous issues posted on the "support" forum. I did however find another chunk of potentially useful information in FB's documentation - see **UPDATE** section of OP. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: “Person” is referring to the Facebook user profile there - the page admin must also be an admin, developer or tester of the app. // But does this plugin you are using even have a step implemented to ask for any permissions? If not, then it was probably just accessing the content as “public”, which used to be possible previously using only an app access token.

Comment: OK that clears up a lot. So the owner of the FB account containing the album I'm displaying must also be an admin, dev or tester of the app - it has nothing to do with Wordpress page or user, correct? The plugin does ask for App ID and App Secret. I'm now hoping that once I add the page's admin as a tester of the app, the plugin will start working again... or will it still require an access token, which now needs to be refreshed/updated every 2 months or so?

Comment: Every API call requires an access token, it just depends on what type. Extended page tokens used to have unlimited validity, but updated docs say it will be valid for up to 60 days; not sure which one it actually is at the moment.

Comment: Got it - looks like the plugin needs the ability to accept access tokens, rendering it useless (for my use case) presently.